# How to make animation smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a created a animated logo that can be view on load only, what I am trying achieve is smoothness, there must be some way to make it more smooth, but not sure how to, here is my code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/L4rsatgw/)

Please help!

HTML code

```
<div class="logo-onload">
  <div class="logo-shape1"></div>
  <div class="logo-shape2"></div>
  <div class="logo-shape3"></div>
  <div class="logo-shape4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.logo-onload{position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0; bottom:0;}
.logo-shape1{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/4e9b933c10ade6e9f67221ad0a5f96f3.png) no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:200px; height:200px; display:none;}
.logo-shape2{position:absolute; right:0; top:0; background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/76aedf703b3fcefe6fed03e03f376643.png) no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:200px; height:200px; display:none;}
.logo-shape3{position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0; background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/2efa074230b3d973e9023e064ed4448a.png) no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:200px; height:200px; display:none;}
.logo-shape4{position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0; background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/e4ca14cbb6f077785f634d666c0de4aa.png) no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:200px; height:200px; display:none;}
```

and JS code is

```
$('.logo-shape1').animate({'left': '50%','margin-left': '-100px','margin-top': '-100px','top': '50%'},1500, 'linear').show();
$('.logo-shape2').animate({'right': '50%','margin-right': '-100px','margin-top': '-100px','top': '50%'},1500, 'linear').show();
$('.logo-shape3').animate({'left': '50%','margin-left': '-100px','margin-bottom': '-100px','bottom': '50%'},1500, 'linear').show();
$('.logo-shape4').animate({'right': '50%','margin-right': '-100px','margin-bottom': '-100px','bottom': '50%'},1500, 'linear').show();
```

Comment: You could use some easing so that the animation is not just linear

Comment: I tried adding easing plugin but no effect

Comment: the animation is already smooth, if you want super smooth then use CSS Animation or `requestAnimationFrame()`

Comment: Smooth on what system? Also, can you describe what exactly the animation is doing instead of relying on folks viewing the fiddle? Think of needing to find this months from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use `swing` instead of `linear`. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4rsatgw/1/).

**JS**

`$('.logo-shape1').animate({'left': '50%','margin-left': '-100px','margin-top': '-100px','top': '50%'},1500, 'swing').show();
$('.logo-shape2').animate({'right': '50%','margin-right': '-100px','margin-top': '-100px','top': '50%'},1500, 'swing').show();
$('.logo-shape3').animate({'left': '50%','margin-left': '-100px','margin-bottom': '-100px','bottom': '50%'},1500, 'swing').show();
$('.logo-shape4').animate({'right': '50%','margin-right': '-100px','margin-bottom': '-100px','bottom': '50%'},1500, 'swing').show();`

Comment: Much better! seems to be better than linear

Answer (score 2):

Or just **CSS3** and a bit of jQuery to know when you want to init the animation:

---

**Demo**:

https://jsfiddle.net/4uo2njfh/

---

**CSS**:

```
.logo-onload{
  position:absolute; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  left:0; 
  top:0; 
  bottom:0;
  &.is-loaded {
    .logo-shape {
      &--1 {
        transform:translate(calc(50vw - 100px), calc(50vh - 100px));
      }
      &--2 {
        transform:translate(calc(-50vw + 100px), calc(50vh - 100px));
      }
      &--3 {
        transform:translate(calc(-50vw + 100px), calc(-50vh + 100px));
      }
      &--4 {
        transform:translate(calc(50vw - 100px), calc(-50vh + 100px));
      }
    }
  }
}
.logo-shape{
  position:absolute; 
  width:200px; 
  height:200px; 
  transition:transform 1s ease;
  &--1  {
    background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/4e9b933c10ade6e9f67221ad0a5f96f3.png) no-repeat; 
    background-size:contain;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
  &--2 {
    background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/76aedf703b3fcefe6fed03e03f376643.png) no-repeat; 
    background-size:contain;
    right:0;
    top:0;
  }
  &--3 {
    background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/2efa074230b3d973e9023e064ed4448a.png) no-repeat; 
    background-size:contain;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
  }
  &--4 {
    background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/e4ca14cbb6f077785f634d666c0de4aa.png) no-repeat; 
    background-size:contain;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
  }
}
```

---

**JS**:

```
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.logo-onload').addClass('is-loaded');
  }, 1000);
})
```

---

**HTML**:

```
<div class="logo-onload">
  <div class="logo-shape logo-shape--1"></div>
  <div class="logo-shape logo-shape--2"></div>
  <div class="logo-shape logo-shape--3"></div>
  <div class="logo-shape logo-shape--4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.logo-shape1').animate({'left': '50%','margin-left': '-100px','margin-top': '-100px','top': '50%'},1500, 'linear').show();
$('.logo-shape2').animate({'right': '50%','margin-right': '-100px','margin-top': '-100px','top': '50%'},1500, 'linear').show();
$('.logo-shape3').animate({'left': '50%','margin-left': '-100px','margin-bottom': '-100px','bottom': '50%'},1500, 'linear').show();
$('.logo-shape4').animate({'right': '50%','margin-right': '-100px','margin-bottom': '-100px','bottom': '50%'},1500, 'linear').show();
```

```css
.logo-onload{position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0; bottom:0;}
 .logo-shape1{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/4e9b933c10ade6e9f67221ad0a5f96f3.png) no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:200px; height:200px; display:none;}
 .logo-shape2{position:absolute; right:0; top:0; background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/76aedf703b3fcefe6fed03e03f376643.png) no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:200px; height:200px; display:none;}
 .logo-shape3{position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0; background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/2efa074230b3d973e9023e064ed4448a.png) no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:200px; height:200px; display:none;}
 .logo-shape4{position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0; background:url(https://cdn.img42.com/e4ca14cbb6f077785f634d666c0de4aa.png) no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:200px; height:200px; display:none;}


* {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo-onload">
<div class="logo-shape1"></div>
<div class="logo-shape2"></div>
<div class="logo-shape3"></div>
<div class="logo-shape4"></div>
</div>
```

;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it starts slow but at last speed increased :(

Comment: You can use this comibinated syntax code: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp trey, and try it! :-)